# How to find,copy and rename files in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, copy, rename

I am trying to find all files in a directory and sub-directories and then copy them to a different directory. However some of them have the same name, so I need to copy the files over and then if there are two files have the same name, rename one of those files.

So far I have managed to copy all found files with a unique name over using:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -e $2 ] ; then
    mkdir $2
    echo "Directory created"
fi
if [ ! -e $1 ] ; then
    echo "image source does not exists"
fi
find $1 -name IMG_****.JPG -exec cp {} $2 \;
```

However, I now need some sort of if statement to figure out if a file has the same name as another file that has been copied.

Comment: Did you really do `****` in the `find`?

Comment: One `*` matches all, you don't need four of them. If you want to match exactly four characters, you can do `????` where each `?` matches only one character. Also, you need to quote `"IMG_????.JPG"` (like I did) to prevent shell from expanding it. You probably got lucky and there is no `IMG_????.JPG` in the directory you are calling `find` from, so the pattern is kept intact.

Comment: ah i see, yeah i just tested that there. thanks :)

Comment: Sure! I recommend reading this page: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls it has good information where beginners (myself included) usually get wrong with bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are on linux, you are probably using `cp` from coreutils.  If that is the case, let it do the backup for you by using `cp --backup=t`

Comment: i havent managed to get it working but this seems to be in the right direction for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach: put the list of files in a variable and copy each file looking if the copy operation succeeds. If not, try a different name.

In code:

```
FILES=`find $1 -name IMG_****.JPG | xargs -r`
for FILE in $FILES; do
    cp -n $FILE destination
    # Check return error of latest command (i.e. cp)
    # through the $? variable and, in case
    # choose a different name for the destination
done
```

Inside the for statement, you can also put some incremental integer to try different names incrementally (e.g., name_1, name_2 and so on, until the cp command succeeds).

Comment: `cp` will simply overwrite existing files

Comment: It's not a dry-run mode: on my Linux distro cp -n a b copies a in b if b does not exist.

Comment: You are right, `-n` is `--no-clobber`. I confused it with the flag from other commands. The answer is fine now.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned in the question that I am only learning linux for the first time, so could you explain what the parts of your code do please? sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
for file in $1/**/IMG_*.jpg ; do  
  target=$2/$(basename "$file") 
  SUFF=0 
  while [[ -f "$target$SUFF" ]] ; do 
    (( SUFF++ )) 
  done
  cp "$file" "$target$SUFF"
done
```

in your script in place of the `find` command to append  integer suffixes to identically-named files

Answer (score 0):

You can use rsync with the following switches for more control

```
 rsync --backup --backup-dir=DIR --suffix=SUFFIX -az <source dire> <destination dir>
```

Here (from [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync))

> **-b, --backup**
>
> With this option, preexisting destination files are renamed as each file is transferred or deleted. You can control where the backup file goes and what (if any) suffix gets appended using the --backup-dir and --suffix options.
>
> **--backup-dir=DIR**
>
> In combination with the --backup option, this tells rsync to store all backups in the specified directory on the receiving side. This can be used for incremental backups. You can additionally specify a backup suffix using the --suffix option (otherwise the files backed up in the specified directory will keep their original filenames).
>
> **--suffix=SUFFIX**
>
> This option allows you to override the default backup suffix used with the --backup (-b) option. The default suffix is a ~ if no --backup-dir was specified, otherwise it is an empty string.

You can use `rsycn` to either sync two folders on local file system or on a remote file system. You can even do syncing over `ssh` connection.

`rsync` is amazingly powerful. See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) for all the options.